# Why does the Pythons __call__ return the same Decorator instance?

Tags: python, decorator, call

```
class Decorator:
def __init__(self, C):
    self.C = C

def __call__(self, *args):
    self.wrapped = self.C(*args)
    return self


@Decorator
class C:
    def __init__(self, attr):
        self.attr = attr

x = C('hello')
y = C('world')
print(x)
print(y)
```

Result:

```
<__main__.Decorator object at 0x000000000056A400>
<__main__.Decorator object at 0x000000000056A400>
```

I cannot understand why the same instance of the class Decorator is returned in the method `__call__`.

Comment: You wrote `return self`; why would you expect it to return a different object?

Comment: I thought the code was supposed to be equivalent to:

Comment: x = Decorator(C)('hello')

Comment: y = Decorator(C)('world')

Comment: But it is not; `Decorator` is called where the class is declared, not where it is instantiated. If you understand that `C('hello')` is calling the `__call__` method, then you should understand why that method returns `self` (i.e. it returns `C`). You call it again, and it returns `C` again.

Comment: where C is without @Decorator

Comment: You decorated one class with `@Decorator`, so your code executes the `Decorator` constructor once to create one `Decorator` object. It cannot be equivalent to any code which creates two `Decorator` objects.

Comment: But self in __call__ belongs to an instance of Decorator, not of C

Comment: It refers to the one, single instance of `Decorator` which your code creates; it is also the case that that instance of `Decorator` is bound to the name `C`.

Comment: You get one `decorator` instance, but 2 instances of `C`

Comment: If I understand correctly, the decorator via @ is always singleton?

Comment: You could create more instances of your `Decorator` class by decorating more things with it - so it is not a singleton, no. Nor is the class `C` a singleton; your `__call__` method creates a new instance of it every time.

Comment: Okay, I think I get it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Decorators are 'binded' to the class, not the instance. Adding a counter makes it clearer:

```
class Decorator:
    count = 0

    def __init__(self, C):
        self.C = C

    def __call__(self, *args):
        self.count += 1
        self.wrapped = self.C(*args)
        print('Decorator counter: %d' % self.count)
        return self


@Decorator
class C:
    count = 0

    def __init__(self, attr):
        self.count += 1
        self.attr = attr
        print(self)
        print('C counter: %d' % self.count)


x = C('hello')
y = C('world')
print(x)
print(y)
```

Out:

```
<__main__.C object at 0x1070ec050>
C counter: 1 # adds one to each instance
Decorator counter: 1
<__main__.C object at 0x1070ec0d0>
C counter: 1 # adds one to each instance
Decorator counter: 2 # sums up!
<__main__.Decorator object at 0x1070e7fd0>
<__main__.Decorator object at 0x1070e7fd0>
```

Comment: Okay, so the decorator is always singleton in this case. Thanks!